# How to pass parameter to webservices

Tags: php

i want to pass parameter for using web services. how can i pass this. i have passed like this. is this correct...?

```
    $TemplateId = $_POST["template_id"];
    $MetafamilyId = $_POST["metafamily_id"];
    $MatchType = $_POST["match_type_name"];
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $password = md5(trim($_POST["password"]));

    $data = array("TemplateId" => $TemplateId,
                    "MetafamilyId" => $MetafamilyId,
                    "MatchType" => $MatchType,
                    "name" => $name,
                    "password" => $password );
    $postData= json_encode($data);
    $url="http://google.com";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);

    $getdata=curl_exec($ch);
    echo $getdata;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Have you tried it? Try it and if it's working fine, It's correct. After trying, if it's giving error, you can ask here. If it's working fine, you can ask for improvement if you feel like so.

Comment: try json or xml posting depending upon the api provider